# How to add seed in Crawler4j at the runtime?

Tags: java, runtime, web-crawler, crawler4j

I am using crawler4j and I need to add links at runtime. Let say , I add a seed 'LinkA' and crawler4j started crawling it. While program is running , I want to add one more seed 'LinkB'. Can it be done ? if yes , how ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add other seeds at runtime in your WebCrawler. For example add in your visit method the following lines:

```
this.myController.addSeed("http://The page you want to crawl");
```